# Convert an int-value to a resource uri

Tags: java, android, uri

i have implemented an android-project which plays a random song. So i have an int-array like this:

```
int [] playlist_stadt    = {R.raw.black_a, R.raw.black_b, R.raw.black_c};
```

for the random play i wrote:

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = playlist_stadt[r.nextInt(playlist_stadt.length)];
PlayMusic(i);
```

what i dont understand is following:

```
textView.setText(i);
```

textview shows: `res/raw/black_c.mp3`

```
Log.e("Output: ", "" + i);
String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + i;
```

in the log is i an number and not the same string how in the textview:

```
Output: 2130968577
203-06 13:09:23.680: E/Output:(31456): android.resource://com.example.testproject2130968577
```

can s.o. explain me this and how to convert the int-value, that i use it as an resource uri path?
thanks in advance and sry for my english

Comment: Have you tried `Log.e("Output: ", String.valueOf(i))` ?

Comment: try Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://packagename/" + i);

Comment: hi beto, with string.valueof(i) it is the same result. an int-value is logged

Comment: @ JaiSoni,
i tried it like this, but get an error, because i is an int-value. i have to convert it i think, so that i have a string like "/raw/black_c.mp3" and not an int-value

Comment: I converted a drawable into a `Uri`, successfully, using this: `Uri.parse("android.resource://your_package_name/"
                                + R.drawable.name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getResources().getResourceEntryName(i) should get you the mp3 name you are looking for.

i is the resource ID generated by aapt in gen/R.java

[Android Accessing Resources Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

The reason textView.setText(i) returns the mp3 resource name is because you are actually calling setText(int resId)

[setText(int resId) JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

You are passing an int parameter which Android interprets as a resource ID and does the getResourceEntryName conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "valueOf(i)", otherwise it will try to look up the location of i and not use the value of i.

Comment: its the same result user214275